# Pulling in last 3 youtube video from my channel

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm currently able to pull in the most recent YouTube video from my channel, but I want to change this to display that last 3, but I can seem to get it to work.

I'm currently using this JavaScript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function showVideo(response) {
        if(response.data && response.data.items) {
            var items = response.data.items;
            if(items.length>0) {
                var item = items[0];
                var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' class='posvid' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                $('#static_video').html(video);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gezzamondoTV/uploads?max-results=1&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
```

This pulls in the most recent, does anyone know what to add or change to get the last 3 recent videos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set the max-results=1 parameter from the URL to 3.

Then write the javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showVideo(response) {
        if(response.data && response.data.items) {
            var items = response.data.items;
            for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {
                var item = items[i];
                var videoid = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+item.id;
                console.log("Latest ID: '"+videoid+"'");
                var video = "<iframe width='420' height='315' class='posvid' src='"+videoid+"' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>"; 
                $('#static_video'+i).html(video);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/gezzamondoTV/uploads?max-results=3&orderby=published&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=showVideo"></script>
```

And then in the html, display the three videos like this:

```
<div id="static_video0"><h2>Video 1</h2></div>
<div id="static_video1"><h2>Video 2</h2></div>
<div id="static_video2"><h2>Video 3</h2></div>
```

Comment: Yeah thought this but there an issue.  In the HTML i use <div id="static_video"><h2>Latest video blog</h2></div> ti display the most recent video via the ID but how can i get the other 2 video to show?

Comment: Nice one. Cheers for that.

Comment: One last thing. is it easy to put these into a list so i can make these 3 videos side by side

Comment: Yeah, that's a css issue.
<div id="static_video0" class="myVideo"><h2>Video 1</h2></div>
<div id="static_video1" class="myVideo"><h2>Video 2</h2></div>
<div id="static_video2" class="myVideo"><h2>Video 3</h2></div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

And then in the css put:

.myVideo{
   float:left;
}